# How to prevent SQL Agent job from being executed

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Agent job that I have disabled, both via the SSMS UI and via T-SQL (see query below) but everyday at 09:48 AM the job is still being executed by the mssql_etl user (the job has no schedule shown in its properties).  How can I definitively prevent execution of the job by other jobs or by anything else (other than by deleting the job)?

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_update_job
@job_name = '(85) AcmeLoad',
@enabled = 0
```

I have also searched all jobs and their steps using the query below and didn't find anything other than the actual job itself:

```
-- only 1 result: (85) AcmeLoad
SELECT sysjobs.name AS JobName
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sysjobs 
    LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sysjobsteps ON sysjobsteps.job_id = sysjobs.job_id
WHERE 
    sysjobs.name LIKE '%Acme%' 
    OR sysjobsteps.command LIKE '%Acme%' 
GROUP BY sysjobs.name
```

Obviously I am missing something here.  I am a software developer; we have no DBA type at the moment.

Comment: Rename the job?

Comment: @dfundako Good idea, thanks.  I just did that, hopefully it works tomorrow morning!  I still don't understand where I went wrong in attempting to disable the job.  Also, I have set up an Outlook reminder so that I can try moving the data file before the job kicks off so that nothing gets processed.

Comment: You can also insert a step before all the others that does nothing but quits the job with failure, preventing anything else from happening. This step could of course also be customized to check specific conditions (like the user name) and `THROW`/`RAISERROR` if it doesn't think the job should proceed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Another great idea, thanks.  I attempted to add a dummy T-SQL step but that errored out when I clicked OK and it wiped out both the one original step and the dummy step I was attempting to add.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the original step back, though I can likely guess at its original settings.

Comment: Might be a scheduled task. Bit hacky but people do do that sometimes. Or it might be a client application

Comment: @Charlieface Good point.  The original author was quite an ETL expert so I can't imagine him putting in a hack but I am still perplexed as to how the job executes when it is disabled (what is the purpose of disabling a job if it doesn't prevent execution?).  Anyway, between renaming the job and me inadvertently wiping out the job step, it's pretty much guaranteed no data file will get processed tomorrow! :)  I'd still like to know the proper way to prevent job execution in a fool-proof manner.